# Comparison test for alternating series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Give $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$ where $a_n \geq 0$, if we have that 
$$0\leq c_n \leq a_n \leq b_n,$$
$c_n, b_n$ are monotone decreasing and go to zero, thus $\sum_n (-1)^n c_n$ and $\sum_n (-1)^n b_n$ both converge, can we say anything about $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can we say anything about $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n?$

No, you cannot.

You will have that $a_n \to 0$ (since $0 \le a_n \le b_n \to 0$), but $a_n$ doesn't necessarily decrease *monotonically*.

The question then boils down to finding a counterexample for Leibniz' criterion for the convergence of alternating series when (only) the condition of monotonically decreasing of the absolute value of the terms isn't satisfied.

**Hint:** take $a_n = \tfrac{1}{n}$ for $n$ even and $a_n = \tfrac{1}{n^2}$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: First, the $\;a_n\;$ you gave yields, I think, a convergent alternating signs series, but even if not: I think the example isn't complete until we get $\;c_n,\,b_n\;$ that fulfill the OP's question's conditions.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. You could take $b_n = \tfrac{1}{n}$ and $c_n = \tfrac{1}{n^2}$. Both decrease monotonically to $0$ but the proposed $a_n$ does not (i.e. it goes to $0$ as well, but **not** monotonically), although it stays bounded between these two sequences as requested. Which is why I added the suggestion for $a_n$ as a hint...

Comment: @DonAntonio ... and since the sum of the even terms  diverges while the sum of the odd terms diverges, the series $\sum_n (-1)^n a_n$ diverges.

Comment: That's the idea! (:-)

Comment: @RobertIsrael Your second "diverges" should be "converges"

Comment: The one but last (i.e. the middle one), yes!

Comment: Fair enough${}{}{}$+1

Comment: @zhw Yes, of course that's what I meant.  Thanks for catching it.